Bash Command Substitution in echo/printf doesn't print result on the same line?
Reproducible example
Consider this example:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "[Status] $(killall --wait example)"

Expected output:

[Status] example: no process found

Actual result (being wrong order and 2 lines):

example: no process found
[Status]

Workaround
result=$(killall --wait example 2>&1)
echo "[Status] ${result}"

Questions

How come the output isn't on the same line in the reproducible example?
Apart from the workaround, is there any way to await the result of command substitution and print it on the same line (e.g. perhaps via process substitution with pipes)?


Change:
echo "[Status] $(killall --wait example)"
into:
echo "[Status] $(killall --wait example 2>&1)"
Explanation: killall prints out on standard error instead of standard output.

That's a one-liner version of the workaround. How come every other command substitution (like ls , df , getopt , type , podman) doesn't require a redirection?

You require a redirection when what you want to capture is not printed on standard output, but on standard error. In general, progress and warning messages should not be mixed with the actual output of the command; that's why there are two output file handles.

Thanks! Out of curiosity, are there any other ways of solving this issue (e.g. using a alternative syntax)?

What sort of alternative syntax are you hoping for? Some shells have different redirection operators like &> and of course you can use the obsolescent  \backtick syntax` instead of the modern$(command substitution)` syntax.
